# How to show XAML views and their C# files in UML class diagrams?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uml, class-diagram

I have a bunch of XAML Views (.xaml files) and their corresponding C# (.cs files) in a package.

How would I show them in a UML class diagram?

Comment: As they're the same class, just partially defined in each file you wouldn't show them as separate classes in a UML class diagram.

Comment: So I'd just leave the package empty? Or not add it at all?

Comment: Each View *class* consists of one `.xaml` and a `.cs` file (infact you can see that the `.cs` file class definition starts `public partial class `). Therefore, if your package contains 6 Views then you will have 6 classes to show on your UML class diagram.

Comment: @ChrisBD This sounds like the start of a very interesting answer which could be useful to other people as well.

Comment: @Ruttzn Two clarifications please:  1) When you say "package", do you refer to a .net package or an UML package? 2) When you say you want to show the files, do you mean the classes contained in those files (class diagram) or do you want to show how the different source files relate to the classes it contains (deployment diagram)?

Answer (score 0):

Each View **class** consists of one `.xaml` and a `.cs` file (in fact you can see that the `.cs` file class definition starts `public partial class` ).

Therefore, if your package contains 6 Views then you will have 6 classes to show on your UML class diagram.

It is popular practice to structure WPF applications using Model-View-ViewModel pattern.

In this situation you'll have at least 4 files for one UI page.

For example, **PageOneView** consists of `PageOneView.xaml` and `PageOneView.cs` that uses **PageOneViewModel** (`PageOneViewModel.cs`) as its data context (it provides a data binding and manipulation source) and **PageOneModel** (`PageOneModel.cs`) would be the data.

If, however, you then want to show your program structure and relationships on a class diagram, then you'd have only 3 classes with relational links (as a View references the ViewModel which in turn references the Model).

In reality the ViewModel may reference multiple Models or classes that act as a data source such as multiple database, data table access.

Comment: according to [official microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/) "Classes and structs are two of the basic constructs of the common type system in .NET. C# 9 adds records, which are a kind of class. Each is essentially a data structure that encapsulates a set of data and behaviors that belong together as a logical unit." statement "class consists of one .xaml and a .cs file" is false (proof: Reflection cannot provide any invormation about files; counter-example: there are classes in vb.net, but no .cs files)

Comment: Please refer to the OP's question and stay on topic. The OP did not ask about the semantics of what Microsoft's definition of what a class is, only that they had a confusion of whether the XAML and C# files related to a View are handled as two separate classes when documented on a UML class diagram.